# The existence of a local orthonormal frame of a hermitian vector bundle

Tags: complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex manifold. Let $E$ be a hermitian vector bundle with a given hermitian metric over
$X$. On a local trivialization open subset, is there a smooth orthonormal local frame?  is there a holomorphic orthonormal local frame?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's always a (local) smooth unitary frame, just as in the real orthonormal case, as you can do Gram-Schmidt. Since the only holomorphic functions of constant magnitude are constants, the only unitary frames that can be holomorphic are *constant* frames on a trivial bundle.

Comment: Thank you ! Maybe I haven't understand your answer yet. Please excuse my stupidity. Does the Gram-Schmidt process break the smoothness of the original section? Does the holomorphic local orthonomal frame exist or not on earth (i.e., does a constant frame exist locally? )

Comment: No, Gram-Schmidt is perfectly smooth, but not holomorphic. Unless you have a globally trivial (or flat) bundle, having a constant frame in one trivialization will not translate to a constant frame in another, overlapping trivialization.